# Run a function published in Webapp from a Google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cors, google-sites

I want to run a function in a webapp from a google site as `onload` function.

`code.gs`

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page"); 
}

function myfunc(datavalues) {
      var sheetURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET-ID-IS-HERE';
     // Current Active Sheet
     var activeGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
     var activeSheet = activeGoogleSheet.getActiveSheet();
      activeSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(datavalues[0]);
      activeSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(datavalues[1]);
     // ---------------------------------------------------- //
}
```

`page.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <body>
  </body>
  
  
  <script>
       // function run from code.gs
       function runfunc(values){
                 google.script.run.myfunc(values);
       }
       
  </script>
</html>
```

Finally, i have following code embeded in google site :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/WEBAPPURL/exec"></script>
<script>
    function loadFunc(){
         var values = ['aaaa',123];
         runfunc(values);       
 }
</script>


<body onload='loadFunc()'>

<body/>
</html>
```

This should write the values to the google sheet, but it is not working. Is it even possible to run function like this from webapp? Is something run or is there an alternative?

---

Update on the problem:
The `code.gs` is updated with `doPost`

`code.gs`

```
    function doGet(e){
     console.log("get request");
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page"); 
    }
    
    function myfunc(datavalues) {
          var sheetURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET-ID-IS-HERE';
         // Current Active Sheet
         var activeGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
         var activeSheet = activeGoogleSheet.getActiveSheet();
          activeSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(datavalues[0]);
          activeSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(datavalues[1]);
         // ---------------------------------------------------- //
    }
// Post method
function doPost(datavalues){
  console.log("post Request");
// check the parameters


 if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
  var datavalues =  JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(e.parameter)); 
  console.log(datavalues);
  var sheetURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/URL/';
     // Current Active Sheet
     var activeGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
     var activeSheet = activeGoogleSheet.getActiveSheet();
     // first empty row
     var dataRow = activeSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;
     // ---------------------------------------------------- //
     // writing data to the sheet
     // ---------------------------------------------------- //
          activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,1).setValue(datavalues['a']);
         activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,2).setValue(datavalues['b']);
     // ---------------------------------------------------- // 
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
```

Code embedded in google site :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function postRequest(url, data) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    credentials: 'omit';
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    body:  JSON.stringify(data);
 });
}

function onloadfunc(){
console.log('loadding');
var data = {'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'};
postRequest('https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/WEBAPP/exec', data).then(function(response) {
    console.log("ok");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
</script>


<body onload="onloadfunc()">
<body/>


</html>
```

Update to both `doPost` and the function to postrequest. but still does not work.

The error in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
> Access to fetch at
> 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/WEBAPPURL/exec'
> from origin 'https://2008039421-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled.

---

I added `mode:'no-cors'` to the `fetch` and that runs the `onloadfunc()` now and runs the `fetch`. It gives me other error regarding the `fetch` or the function but now it gives me the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

The webapp is open to use for anyone in the network and the google site is also using it through the network. So it should not have problem with authentication. I do not know what is wrong now.

---

Latest error with `JSON.stringify`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function postRequest(url, data) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    credentials:'include',
    body: data
  });
}
function onloadfunc(){
console.log('loading');
var data = JSON.stringify({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'});
 postRequest('https://script.google.com/a/WEBAPP/exec', data).then(function(response) {
 var div = document.getElementById('errorOutput');
      div.innerHTML = "response"+response;
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function(error) {
     var div = document.getElementById('errorOutput');
      div.innerHTML = "error"+error;
    console.log(error);});
}
</script>
<body onload="onloadfunc()">
<div id="errorOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`code.gs`

```
// Post method
function doPost(e){
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null, 2));
  // check the parameters
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
  console.log(e);
  var datavalues = e.parameter; 
  var sheetURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEETURL/';
     // Current Active Sheet
     var activeGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
     var activeSheet = activeGoogleSheet.getActiveSheet();
     // first empty row
     var dataRow = activeSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;
     // ---------------------------------------------------- //
     // writing data to the sheet
     // ---------------------------------------------------- //

          activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,1).setValue(datavalues.a);
     
         activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,2).setValue(datavalues.b);
     // ---------------------------------------------------- // 
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

With this, the `doPost` is called and it works!!!
Only problem now i have is my dictionary is passed wrong.
In site it is `{'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'}` but the total argument passed looks like (result of `console.log(e)`) :

```
{parameter={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=}, contextPath=, contentLength=31, queryString=, parameters={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=[]}, postData=FileUpload}
```

Somehow extra `=` is added and then the dictionary is passed as it is.

Comment: Web apps that are embedded into Google Sites are put inside an iframe so won't be able to interact directly. The frame has an ID of `userHtmlFrame`, have you tried using `document.getElementById('userHtmlFrame').contentWindow.runfunc(values);` inside the `loadFunc()`?

Comment: @Rafa That may work, but only if both frames are from the same domain.

Comment: You can POST from your Google site code using `Fetch` api and receive it in `doPost()`.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo The code suggested by you does not work.

Comment: @TheMaster Can you help me a big what you meant by use of Fetch Api.

Comment: @TheMaster I added `doPost` and fetch for post request but nothing happens sadly. I have posted my code above.

Comment: Hey, Now i updated the things you said and still the same problem :( I also published new version of webapp

Comment: And what did you ``catch``?

Comment: I get : `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: @TheMaster I have also included the error message in console.

Comment: Send it as a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) i.e.,  Change ContentType to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and 2. don't stringify data: `body:data`. If plain `data`(as in 2) doesn't work, send `data` as `body:new URLSearchParams(data)`

Comment: I get the same error with those two changes : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`

Comment: With `cors`, I get `Failed to Fetch` `Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/a/xxxxxxxx/exec' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Just to be clear,  publish settings is `Anyone` **even anonymous** right? Also, in script editor>View> Executions>Clear "Run as me" filter... was there ever a post request logged?

Comment: I dont have `even anonymous` options, but it is set to `Anyone within network`, and in `View>Executions` no post request apparently.

Comment: @hadi You need to set it `even anonymous`(See [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)). Contact your admin. Admin will be able to set it.

Comment: Also, some typos `;` is used in the fetch request instead of `,`. `credentials: 'omit';`, `body:  JSON.stringify(data);`. If your admin opens up your web-app, [edit] your question with the latest script.

Comment: Yes, i corrected the typos. But it is going to be tough to open the script for anyone. The script is for the network and Post request is also in the network, so this should work in my opinion in some way

Comment: Probably won't work. But you may try setting `credentials:'include'`. Also, during development, set doPost to a simple function like. `function doPost(e){console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null, 2))}`

Comment: Hey @TheMaster That worked! But with `mode:'no-cors'`. Thank you so much for your help!! I have small issue though now (sorry about that). The data sent by `postRequest` is read as `{parameter={[object Object]=}, contextPath=, contentLength=15, queryString=, parameters={[object Object]=[]}, postData=FileUpload}` . I tired `JSON.stringify` and then it is read as `parameter={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=}, contextPath=, contentLength=31, queryString=, parameters={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=[]}, postData=FileUpload}`

Comment: @TheMaster if you asnwer with your comments, i can accept it as answer, I used your solutions with `credential:include`, `no-cors` ,`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `body:data`, and it worked. the main things were `credentials` and `no-cors`.

Comment: @TheMaster and regarding the current issue, I am passing the data as ` var data = JSON.stringify({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'});` and then in the `doPost` using `var datavalues = JSON.parse(e.parameter);` to get back the data. The total values passed looks like `{parameter={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=}, contextPath=, contentLength=31, queryString=, parameters={{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=[]}, postData=FileUpload}`  . I dont get why is there extra `=` sign in `parameter` and if I now use `JSON.parse(e.parameter)`  I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: o
    at doPost(Code:45)`

Comment: Missed your comment. `I dont get why is there extra = sign in parameter and if I now use JSON.parse(e.parameter) I get ` `=` is just seen in logger. It is equal to `:` and the underlying is a valid json object (not a string). You said you're sending it as `body:data` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906169/run-a-function-published-in-webapp-from-a-google-site?noredirect=1#comment102329828_57906169). Or you sending it as string `body: JSON.stringify(data)`? Can you show how you're sending `body:`?

Comment: Yeah @TheMaster the `=` sign that is added there seem to cause the problem. I dont get where is it coming from. If I do `console.log("datavalues",datavalues)` without `JSON.parse` like you said, I get `datavalues {{"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}=}`. And `console.log(datavalues.a);` gives `undefined`.

Comment: In the site itself, if i do `console.log(JSON.stringify({'a':'xxx','b','ppp'}))`, the output is correct as expected ` {"a":"xxx","b":"ppp"}`

Comment: Sure, I have pasted my code again in the question. the relevant lines are `var data = JSON.stringify({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'});` in `onloadfunc` and then in `fetch` itself, I just assign `body:data`.

Comment: Great. What happens if you change `var data = JSON.stringify({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'});` to 1. `var data = {'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'};` and 2. `var data = new URLSearchParams({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'});` and log the `e.parameter`? `=` is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Goal:

- Run a specific function in a WebApp published in a domain using Google apps script with

  - Access: Anyone from domain
- from

  - New Google sites published in the same domain.

#### Issue:

- **CORS:** Both the Google apps script web app(hereafter, Gas-webapp) and user code in Google sites(hereafter, Gs webapp) run in iframes of different origin- `https://[DIFFERENT_URL].googleusercontent.com` sandboxed in `*google.com`.

#### Script Flow:

- Use `Fetch` api to `POST` data from Google sites to web-app.
- Receive `POST` request from Google sites and execute the function.

#### Required Reading:

- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [Fetch API Spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode)

#### Notes:

- Gas web-app by default provides the following CORS response header to any authenticated CORS request:

  - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`
- However, If the requested is unauthenticated or if the script errors out, You're redirected to Google's login page/error page; Both pages doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set and access will be blocked from all web pages.
- The only exception to the unauthenticated requests mentioned above is  publishing Gas web-app with access: `Anyone,`**`even anonymous`**.
- Gas web-app doesn't allow `OPTIONS` method. Hence, all requests that are [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) will fail.
- The only remaining CORS option compatible with gas-web app is [`Simple requests`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), that are not preflighted by the browser.
- However, simple `POST` requests are essentially unauthenticated. In this script, We use the [`credentials` option](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) in the request to include third party credentials. Here, we are after User account's Google's credentials. By using this option, We are essentially authenticating using user account's Google's  credentials.  The following conditions must be satisfied to use this option:

  - The user must be logged in to Google, so as to have login cookies to send with the post request.
  - Third party cookies must be enabled in browser, as iframe is of different origin.
- The [request mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) can be set to `cors` or `no-cors`.
- However, If `cors` is set, according to the [spec documentation](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials), the following response header must be provided by the gas web-app to post request with credentials:

  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

This is not provided by the gas-webapp. Though the request will be send(as it is not preflighted), the response can't be received(not shared), i.e., `doPost` will still run, but response cannot be received by the gs-webapp.

- If `no-cors` is set, fetch will return an ["opaque filtered response"](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque)(a empty response).

  > An opaque filtered response is a filtered response whose type is "opaque", URL list is the empty list, status is 0, status message is the empty byte sequence, header list is empty, body is null, and trailer is empty.
- In essence, You can do a one way communication from gs-web-app to gas-web-app, when access is set to `Anyone`(not anonymous).
- `POST` requests made with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` must be a string of format: `input1=1&input2=4`. [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) could be used to craft such string from objects.

#### Snippet:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function postRequest(url, data) {
      return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        mode: 'no-cors',//or 'cors': Though request fails, doPost will execute
        headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',//**Modified**
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        credentials:'include',//Access Credentials in browser cookies
        body: data
      });
    }
    function onloadfunc(){
    console.log('loading');
    var data = (new URLSearchParams({'a':'xxx','b':'ppp'})).toString();//**MODIFIED**
     postRequest('https://script.google.com/a/WEBAPP/exec', data).then(function(response) {
    //************OPAQUE RESPONSE: Nothing will be received************
     var div = document.getElementById('errorOutput');
        response.text(res=>
          div.innerHTML = "response "+res)
            console.log("ok");
        }).catch(function(error) {
         var div = document.getElementById('errorOutput');
          div.innerHTML = "error"+error;
        console.log(error);});
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="onloadfunc()">
    <div id="errorOutput"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`code.gs`

```js
    // Post method
    function doPost(e){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null, 2));
      // check the parameters
      if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
      console.log(e);
      var datavalues = e.parameter; 
      var sheetURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEETURL/';
         // Current Active Sheet
         var activeGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL);
         var activeSheet = activeGoogleSheet.getActiveSheet();
         // first empty row
         var dataRow = activeSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;
         // ---------------------------------------------------- //
         // writing data to the sheet
         // ---------------------------------------------------- //
  
              activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,1).setValue(datavalues.a);
         
             activeSheet.getRange(dataRow,2).setValue(datavalues.b);
         //WON'T BE RECEIVED BY the post requester anyway// 
       return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that solution with `URLSearchParams`. This works perfect!
And thank you for the detailed explanation. This helps a lot to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the function at startup with jQuery. It will look like this, add this code in your html file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    loadFunc();
  });

function loadFunc(){
var values = ['aaaa',123];
  google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
            console.log('Success')
          })
        .withFailureHandler(function(msg) {
            console.log('Error : '+msg);
          })
        .myfunc(values);
}
</script>
```

Then you embed the page with iframe on the site and it will load the blank page and execute the function.
You can specify a small iframe size to just have a small space used by the iframe.

Stéphane

Comment: Hi Stephane, this works, but I want the code to execute from the site itself instead of webapp.

Comment: Include an iframe int he site, it is my last answer. You embed the iframe in a small size like 10x10 px so it will be invisible.